# 3D object in front of 2D Sprite (background) , how?

Tags: c++, 2d, sprite, direct3d, augmented-reality

I'm new to Direct3D and I was on a project taking pictures from a webcam and draw some 3D objects in front of it.

I was able to render webcam images as background using Orthogonal Projection.

```
//init matrix


     D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&Ortho, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0.0f, 100.0f);

//some code

     D3DXVECTOR3 position = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
     g_pSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE);
     g_pSprite->Draw(g_pTexture,NULL,&center,&position,0xFFFFFFFF);
     g_pSprite->End();
```

Then I tried to insert a simple triangle in front of it. The Matrices are setup as follow

```
D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorld;


D3DXMatrixTranslation( &matWorld, 0.0f,0.0f,5.0f );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );


D3DXMATRIXA16 matProj;
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &matProj, D3DX_PI / 4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj );
```

5.0 should be < 100.0 and the triangle is supposed to be appear in front of the images. However it does not appear unless set the z position to 0. At position 0, i can see the triangle but background is blank.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would not draw the webcam image in the object space (D3DXSPRITE_OBJECTSPACE) if you intend to use your image solely for background purpose; something like

```
        D3DXVECTOR3 backPos (0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        pBackgroundSprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
        pBackgroundSprite->Draw (pBackgroundTexture,
                           0, 
                           0,
                           &backPos,
                           0xFFFFFFFF);
        pBackgroundSprite->End();
```

should hopefully do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix you could disable depth testing as follows;

```
g_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_FALSE);
```

This way the z-index of the primitives being drawn should reflect the order in which they are drawn.

Also, try using the PIX debugging tool (this is bundled with the DirectX SDK). This is always my first port of call for drawing discrepancies as it allows you to debug each Draw call separately with access to the depth buffer and transformed vertices.